# kubernetes on gke / why a load balancer use is enforced?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Made my way into kubernetes through GKE, currently trying out via kubeadm on bare metal.

In the later environment, there is no need of any specific load balancer; using nginx-ingress and ingresses let one serve service to the www.

Oppositely, on gke, using the same nginx-ingress, or using the gke provided l7, you always end up with a billed load balancer.

What's the reason about that, as it seemed not to be ultimately needed ?

Comment: Hi, It seems you are getting confused at load balancing of layer 3,4 and 7. following article might give you insight about [modern load-balancing and proxying](https://blog.envoyproxy.io/introduction-to-modern-network-load-balancing-and-proxying-a57f6ff80236)

Comment: Humm… Am skilled enough to use all but but frankly my brain cells aren't organized to understand the underlyings of those networking topics. I've read the article; I can understand the benefits of using an L7, but not the reason why such "add-on" is enforced on gke

Comment: In general, when receiving traffic from the outside world, that traffic will be sent to one or more non-ACLd public IP addresses. If you run k8s on bare metals, those BMs can have public IPs, and you can just run ingress on one or more of them. A managed k8s environment, however, for security reasons, will not permit nodes to have public IPs. Instead, managed load balancers are allowed to have public IPs. Those are configured to know the private node IPs hosting ingress for your cluster and will direct traffic accordingly.

Comment: Hello @Jonah B, your comment seems great to be posted as a complete answer. Please do.

Comment: There is a way to skip the Load Balancer entirely, see https://serverfault.com/questions/863569/kubernetes-can-i-avoid-using-the-gce-load-balancer-to-reduce-cost/869453

Not recommended for serious production uses. Fine for poor-man solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes services have few types, each building up on previous one : ClusterIP, NodePort and LoadBalancer. Only the last one will provision LoadBalancer in a cloud environment, so you can avoid it on GKE without fuzz. The question is, what then? Because, in best case you end up with an Ingress (I assume we expose ingress as in your question), that is available on volatile IPs (nodes can be rolled at any time and new ones will get new IPs) and high ports given by NodePort service. Meaning that not only you have no fixed IP to use, but also you would need to open something like http://:31978, which obviously is crap. Hence, in cloud, you have a simple solution of putting a cloud load balancer in front of it with LoadBalancer service type. This LB will ingest the traffic on port 80/443 and forward it to correct backing service/pods.

Comment: thx a lot that makes things clearer. @Suresh Vishnoi was commenting above with this link https://blog.envoyproxy.io/introduction-to-modern-network-load-balancing-and-proxying-a57f6ff80236; sounds like  an L7 kind of improves performance (compared to a bare metal setup), but still, am unsure about this; are there any downfalls not using cloud providers' ?

Comment: depends on what you mean by "using cloud providers". If you mean the ones inside kubernetes, then you should always have the cloud provider enabled for your cloud you use. In most cases the provisioning system will do that for you. It gives you not only things like automatic LB service support, but also for example volume provisioning. On baremetal you usualy need to provide some solution on your own, or imit the regular kube feature set (ie. by not supporting LB services at all, and just exposing everything by a predefined Ingress Controller)

Comment: No i mean by that, when serving sites/services to the "outside world". For example when on gke; does their top levels load balancer (so not the kube one) offers network improvements, things like that.. or are such considerations would still resides in nginx (albeit you're using the nginx ingress project) ?

Comment: To put it simpler; on bare metal, as you're saying, i do imit by exposing through a predefined ingress. Still, my sites/services are still served the same. But sounds like there's a difference and this is what i don't fully understand; as the end result is the "same". I get the security part; but it there any other added value ?

Answer (score 4):

(Reposting my comment above)

In general, when one is receiving traffic from the outside world, that traffic is being sent to one or more non-ACLd public IP addresses.

If you run k8s on bare metals, those BMs can have public IPs, and you can just run ingress on one or more of them.

A managed k8s environment, however, for security reasons, will not permit nodes to have public IPs.

Instead, managed load balancers are allowed to have public IPs. Those are configured to know the private node IPs hosting ingress for your cluster and will direct traffic accordingly.